# Override key binding

Tags: shortcut-keys

I use Inspiron 1460 which need to press <kbd>Fn</kbd> key to enter <kbd>F4</kbd>. This thus make my <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> more difficult because I need to press 3 keys instead two shorter key combination. I want to change the key binding to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> if possible. Can this be achieved? I use CompizSetting to change it before this but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to System Settings, and under the Hardware section click on Keyboard. You'll see Shortcut settings there, and Alt+F4 should be under "Windows."

Comment: Yeah! Thanks for that man. But I want to add here, somehow Alt+Esc won't work as a key binder. I choose Alt+RCtrl as a new key and Wallahhhh!!! It's great. Solve my key binding problem.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help. Just so you know, it's polite to accept someone's answer. It gives them and you a bit of reputation points, and lets people know that a solution was found. It's a win-win-win situation. :)